# Отображение хлебных крошек

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Как организовать на сайте вывод хлебных крошек, как на скриншоте?

[image: Собственно сам скрин]

Comment: Это похоже на хлебные крошки если честно.

Comment: Уточните, на чем сделан ваш сайт.

Comment: html, css блочная верстка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давненько не слышал этого словосочетания.
Обычно это делается исходя из иерархии страниц.

Грубо говоря, у каждой страницы должен быть родитель, что определяется столбцом в базе данных, например, как "parent".

У этой строки, на которую ссылается страница, как на родителя, тоже может быть родитель.

И так до бесконечности.

Теперь пора написать функцию, которая получает параметр конечного объекта и каким-то образом пробегает по БД вычисляя и возвращая все узлы до самого последнего родителя.